# Can special/general relativity be derived from the standard model?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, standard-model

Can [special](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special_relativity)/[general relativity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_relativity) be derived from the [standard model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model)?
For example the time dilatation in strong gravitation? My feeling is yes, but I am not quite sure.

Comment: General relativity, no. Special relativity, guess no, it's one of the assumptions.

Comment: The very articles you linked answer your question quite well - standard model doesn't incorporate general relativity, and it's based on the assumptions of special relativity (SM is a relativistic quantum field theory). So you could derive special (not general) relativity from SM, but what would be the point? It's part of the definition (global Poincaré symmetry), not a prediction or anything.

Comment: I did not link them. It was the editor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Special relativity is used in the SM formulation. It is kinematics, so somehow more basic than interactions between bodies.

A QFT derivation of General Relativity has been the Holy Grail of the field for many years. In the early times, Feynman, Dirac, and the others tackled this problem, but after decades of failures it was more or less considered impossible with the present tools.

This said, there are theories that try to give a quantum description of gravity, like string theory and p-branes, or exotic things like bi-gravity. But, in the best case, they cannot be probed experimentally.

You can't stop theorists from developing new theories (and they certanly shouldn't be stopped!), but my take is that none of this will definitely solve the issue until a whole new generation of particle physics experiments is out and the theories can be tested and guided by evidence. The good thing is that,even if the theories are wrong or completely unapplicable, the mathematical tools and physical insights can always be used for who knows what cool science completely unrelated.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get the answer to the question from *"Special relativity is used in the SM formulation"*. So the answer is YES or NO?

Comment: To formulate the Standard Model you start with Special Relativity. It is a requirement, more than an effect.

Answer (score 2):

According to the following paper and commentaries, general relativity can be derived from a standard model matter field equation combined with some other consistency criteria. If new matter such as dark matter is found then the given procedure could give a new theory of gravity or it might just lead back to general relativity.

How quantizable matter gravitates: a practitioner's guide
http://arxiv.org/abs/1402.6548

via

Igor Khavkine
https://plus.google.com/117198712299497322128/posts/c6Xe1GSxuro

via

https://selectedpapers.net/

Also according to Igor Khavkine's video lecture, not many people know this but a conservative theory of quantum gravity requiring no new fields or dimensions is already known to a better level of understanding than the standard model https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G5O9RKmXyfM